# How do I create a random integer that changes with each x value in a for loop in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, random

Is there a way to make it so that if the output of the randNumber is lower than say, 75, the output of the randNumber will change to a lower number than 85? Like if the random number generator chooses 75 as the first number is there a way to change the value of the rest of the outputs after that to be lower than 85 (what it is set to now).

```
public static void Hypothetical() {
    int x;

    for (x = 0; x <= 4; x++) {
    Random z = new Random();
    int zNumber = z.nextInt(10-5) + 5;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randNumber = rand.nextInt(85-65) + 65;
        if (x  == 0) {
            System.out.println("You may begin running.");
            //TimeUnit.SECONDS.(2);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (x == 1 ) {
            System.out.println("Your first lap was made in " + randNumber + " seconds");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (x==2) {
            System.out.println("Your second lap was made in " + (randNumber + zNumber) + " seconds");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (x==3) {
            System.out.println("Your third lap was made in " + (randNumber + zNumber) + " seconds");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (x==4) {
            System.out.println("Your final lap was made in " + (randNumber + zNumber) + " seconds");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can't you just regenerate/reassign zNumber and randNumber inside the loop?

Comment: Do you really need the number to be different every time, or is it OK if they're different most of the time?  If you're going to generate a sequence of random numbers using `rand.nextInt(20)`, there's a 1/20 chance that any number will be the same as the previous number.  If you want to make sure they're all different, you'll need a different algorithm.

Comment: Please don't totally rewrite questions like this by editing, since it makes comments and answers that others already wrote look idiotic.  Better to delete and ask a new question.  However, it is still not clear what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

```
cond = false;
loop
    if (cond)
        generate values lower than 85
    else
        generate number
        if number < 75, cond = true
```

Answer (score -1):

As I am understanding your question, you want to change the ceiling of your random number. The easiest way I can think of doing this is to introduce modulo ceiling, as shown below. Although, I am not sure what your trying to do.

```
limitRanInt = false
loop
 if( limitRanInt || <rand#> <= 75){
   limitRanInt = true
   <rand#> = <rand#> % 85
   }
endloop
```

Comment: First of all, this question was tagged "java" and I don't know what language you answered in.  But in any case, I don't think a modulo is appropriate in the answer.  The random numbers he's generating are already lower than 85, so a modulo does nothing.  But if you generate a random number from 1 to 85, and then you want to limit it to 75, if use use `% 75`, the results will not be evenly distributed--you will get twice as much of a chance as numbers in the 0..9 range.